# Is it possible to stop an AWS Postgres Aurora Global Database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to run AWS Postgres Aurora Global Database in my staging environment, but I want to stop it overnight and weekends. It seems like this might not be possible?

I have a primary cluster in the EU and a single read replica cluster in the US. If I try and stop the Primary Cluster I get:

```
Stop-db-cluster is not supported for clusters with read replicas 
(Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDBClusterStateFault; Request ID: XXXXXXXX)
```

Is the only way to stop the RDS is to destroy the entire cluster?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurora Global Database doesn't support stopping and stopping global clusters. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database.html#aurora-global-database.limitations):

> The following features **aren't supported** for Aurora global databases:
> **Stopping and starting** the DB clusters within the global database.

It seems that, as you pointed out, the only way would be stop  delete it and recreate later on from a snapshot for instance.